# Can't get haproxy-ingress to work

Tags: kubernetes

I have been trying to get an HAProxy Ingress working on my kubernetes cluster.
I have been following the instructions in the README (https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/tree/master/examples/deployment). I see that haproxy-ingress pod has this in its log:

```
I0617 16:50:31.298997       6 launch.go:181] 
Name:       HAProxy
Release:    v0.9
Build:      git-4220104
Repository: https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress
I0617 16:50:31.299065       6 launch.go:184] Watching for ingress class: haproxy
I0617 16:50:31.299633       6 launch.go:427] Creating API client for https://10.233.0.1:443
I0617 16:50:31.307638       6 launch.go:439] Running in Kubernetes Cluster version v1.18 (v1.18.3) - git (clean) commit 2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40 - platform linux/amd64
F0617 16:50:31.308283       6 launch.go:207] no service with name ingress-controller/ingress-default-backend found: services "ingress-default-backend" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-controller:default" cannot get resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-controller"
```

The one thing to note that didn't seem to work in the README was this:

```
kubectl --namespace=ingress-controller create -f haproxy-ingress.yaml
```

That command failed with this error:

```
error: unable to recognize "haproxy-ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta2"
```

I had to change the apiVersion: `apps/v1beta2` to `apiVersion: apps/v1`

Did that cause the problem?

Thanks!

Upate:

I was able to get the haproxy-ingress pod to finally launch without error.
After much trial and error I final figured out that I need to update the haproxy-ingress "deployment" (via the dashbaord). I only had to add the one line:

```
serviceAccountName: ingress-controller
```

directly after the spec: tag.

I am still not able to get an external address.

when I run

```
kubectl describe ingress app --namespace=ingress-controller
```

I do not see an IP address associated with host.

```
$ kubectl describe ingress app --namespace=ingress-controller
Name:             app
Namespace:        ingress-controller
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  ifs-alpha-kube.cisco.com
                            /   service-nodeport:80 (<error: endpoints "service-nodeport" not found>)
Annotations:                <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                -------
  Normal  CREATE  37m                ingress-controller  Ingress ingress-controller/app
  Normal  UPDATE  18m (x3 over 10h)  ingress-controller  Ingress ingress-controller/app
  Normal  UPDATE  18m (x2 over 19m)  ingress-controller  Ingress ingress-controller/app
```

and if I execute

```
$ kubectl get service -A -o wide
```

I see that no service has an external ip.

Update II

Turns out I don't need to see external ips.

Answer (score 3):

> F0617 16:50:31.308283       6 launch.go:207] no service with name ingress-controller/ingress-default-backend found: services "ingress-default-backend" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:ingress-controller:default" cannot get resource "services" in API group "" in the namespace "ingress-controller"

There seems to be a couple of things going on there, but overall it appears the yaml you linked to expects haproxy to be the *additional* Ingress controller, and not the *only* one -- that's why it's missing the `ingress-default-backend` and the `RoleBinding`

The [docs version](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress/blob/v0.10-beta.2/docs/haproxy-ingress.yaml) (as described by [the fine manual](https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/docs/getting-started/#the-five-minutes-deployment)) seems to be more complete, as it contains the `Service`, `ClusterRoleBinding`, and associated component parts

If you're helm savvy, you may enjoy the [haproxy helm chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/incubator/haproxy-ingress) more, since it is more one-stop-shopping